# Changing the connectionString value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to change the default value of my connectionString in my application. How do I change it such that it redirects to a database in my system?

Here is my code:

```
private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlcn"].ConnectionString.ToString();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not a duplicate, since this question doesn't deal with changing it programattically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you App.config file (or Web.config if it's a web application), there is an element `<connectionStrings>`. You can edit the values listed there to change your connection strings.

You can see the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx) on this topic for more information.

Comment: Thanks! You have been immensely helpful.